# Strange selection behaviour of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection

I'm developing project for both devices - iPhone and iPad. For both devices i have appropriate storyboard. Because paradigm of iPad is little different from iPhone, I created for iPhone and for iPad different controllers for same views. Other controllers I use in both storyboards. I faced with strange bug. In table view selection occurs with one finger touch (for iPhone) but in iPad the same table view cell can be selected only with double touch. Has everybody faced with such strange behaviour? 
Btw, I didn't have any gesture recogniser in problem table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed that strange behaviour by changing way of navigation in slide controller. Also I notices that this "bug" appeared when I added gesture recogniser to table view.